# How to access to non unique subclass of every element during iteration with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am iterating through elements on the website with XPath of each element.

```
//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/main/div[2]/section/div/section/div[4]/div[1]/div[X]
```

`X values:` from `1 to n`. Where X is an ordinal number of the element.

`xpath.getText()` give me the name and price of current item.
I want to download the image also. Class name for the image isn't unique. It same for every element: "`shop-card__image-block`".

How to access"`shop-card__image-block`" for every element? I want to take the link to the image and download it with the name and price.

See the images.

[First image](https://ibb.co/84G27pM)

[Second image](https://ibb.co/zXRK81X)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.findElement(By by)` or `element.findElements(By by)` to get child element(s). See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/locating-child-nodes-of-webelements-in-selenium.

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
int divSize = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div[1]/main/div[2]/section/div/section/div[4]/div[1]/div")).size();

for (int i = 1; i<= divSize; i++) {
    WebElement parentDiv = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div[1]/main/div[2]/section/div/section/div[4]/div[1]/div['"+i+"']")));
    WebElement image = parentDiv.findElement(By.xpath(".//descendant::div[contains(@class,'shop-card__image-block')]"));
    
    // now image is a web element, you can perform a click on it like image.click(); or any other operation. 
}
```

now image is a web element, you can perform a click on it like `image.click();` or any other operation.

trust this helps.

Comment: I made it already on this way:

`private By slika = By.tagName("img");`
`var linkSLike = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div[1]/main/div[2]/section/div/section/div[3]/div[1]/div["+i+"]")).findElement(slika).getAttribute("data-src");`

Thanks anyway

Comment: Well, I wasn't aware of that. Since there wasn't any note/comment on your post. Anyway, Glad you made it to work.